# Where can I find the SensorData dataset referred to in the PolyBase Guide

Tags: azure-sql-database

In the PolyBase Queries section of the PolyBase Guide,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt652313.aspx, it shows several samples using SensorData. Where can I find that dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The file is called [HVAC.csv](http://s3.amazonaws.com/hw-sandbox/tutorial14/SensorFiles.zip) and is available as a sample dataset whenever you provision a HDInsight cluster in the following directory:

`/HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/`

Alternately get it from here:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/hw-sandbox/tutorial14/SensorFiles.zip

Comment: Was this answer of no use to you?